# Duplicate iptable rules

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I have this iptable rules:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A fail2ban-ssh -s xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
```

The lines

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
```

and

```
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
```

seems to be duplicated or written twice. How can I remove the duplicate?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

List with line numbers and delete by number.

```
iptables --line-numbers --list
```

Then delete one rule using it's line number. Then repeat (line numbers change for following rules when one is deleted so re-list before deleting another).

```
iptables -D INPUT 6
```

Comment: Thanks for this buddy! Will accept this in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Will this remain persistent after a reboot?

Answer (score 23):

```
iptables-save | uniq | iptables-restore
```

That is all you need really.

Comment: AFAICT, this will only remove adjacent duplicates. It will fail to remove non-adjacent duplicates.

Comment: @sampablokuper Then just pipe to `sort -u` before `uniq`.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou you need to be careful about sorting everything.  In the example above, would that not reorder the `-j RETURN` to *before* the `-s xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 -j REJECT` rule, meaning the latter rule would never be seen?

Comment: @mwfearnley Ha !  You’re right, indeed.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou `sort`'s `-u` flag already removes duplicates, so there's no need to use `uniq` at all after that.

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to delete double lines that are **directly one after anothe**r you can export, unify and reimport it with

```
mkdir ~/tmp
iptables-save > ~/tmp/iptables.conf
uniq /tmp/iptables.conf > ~/tmp/iptables_new.conf
iptables-restore < ~/tmp/iptables_new.conf
```

If you want to delete other lines use an editor on ~/tmp/iptables.conf
 before you reimport it the same way.

Check your new rules with

```
iptables-save
```

Comment: If stripping adjacent duplicates is what you seek, then Ricky Neff's [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/890065/) is more secure, because it avoids exposing firewall the rules to other users who have access to `/tmp`.

Comment: thx, you are right, you shouldn't use /tmp cause it is world-readable. I changed it to `~/tmp`

Answer (score 4):

A comment to fail2ban: fail2ban seems to add its iptables rules itself. So you should not store these rules with e.g. iptables-save. Then after a reboot the rules will be doubled (your saved rule + the rule added by fail2ban).

Answer (score 3):

Delete all duplicated lines except COMMIT

```
/sbin/iptables-save | awk '!COMMIT||!x[$0]++' | /sbin/iptables-restore
```

Comment: Didn't made any changes with "!COMMIT||" part! But in my iptables-save I had COMMIT only at the bottom. So it worked perfectly. But still wondering what was wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `awk '/COMMIT/||...` to keep the COMMIT lines?  I think `!COMMIT` would keep every line, since the COMMIT variable is never set.

Answer (score 0):

I am using such a small bash script which runs through cron.

```
     #!/bin/bash 
         readarray -t tabl_lines <<< "$(iptables -nL INPUT --line-number | grep "fail2ban-ssh")"
            i=''
            for tline in "${tabl_lines[@]}"
            do 
            #skip the first result
            if [ -n "$i" ]; then
            sudo iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
            # if necessary, you can erase and other rules, 
            # because they usually repeat the same number of times
            # sudo iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 21 -j fail2ban-vsftpd
save_iptables=yes
            else 
            i=start_remove
            fi
            done
if [ "$save_iptables" == "yes" ]; then
/sbin/service iptables save
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to [Igor](https://www.krazyworks.com/remove-duplicate-iptables-rules/) for his script. I feel it's useful:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/service iptables save
/sbin/iptables-save | awk '/^COMMIT$/ { delete x; }; !x[$0]++' > /tmp/iptables.conf
/sbin/iptables -F
/sbin/iptables-restore < /tmp/iptables.conf
/sbin/service iptables save
/sbin/service iptables restart
if [ -f /tmp/iptables.conf ] ; then /bin/rm -f /tmp/iptables.conf ; fi
```

Caveat: works only on Redhat / Centos, or other distro with iptables service. Thus my shorted mod for cron/one time use is:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iptables-save | awk '/^COMMIT$/ { delete x; }; !x[$0]++' > /tmp/iptables.conf
/sbin/iptables -F
/sbin/iptables-restore < /tmp/iptables.conf
if [ -f /tmp/iptables.conf ] ; then /bin/rm -f /tmp/iptables.conf ; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an improved version using awk. This removes all duplicates in the -A rules, keep the rest of the strucuture correct, which is probably what you want :

`iptables-save|awk '{if(/^-A /){if (!a[$0]++)print $0}else if (!/^-A /){print $0}}'|iptables-restore`